# Add element for each value of the key - JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, forms, serialization

I have a form with user input and I serialize the data in JSON. What I want is that for each value of a specified key I want to add a prefix when the user should fill the input, like if the user introduce 123, the final output should be **`http://123`**, but just for one input field, not for every input field in my form.

This is my code, everything is working till I do the console log:

```js
function convertFormToJSON(form) {
  var array = jQuery(form).serializeArray();
  var json = {};

  jQuery.each(array, function() {
    json[this.name] = this.value || '';
  });

  return json;
}
console.log(convertFormToJSON(document.getElementById("myform")));

var blah=convertFormToJSON(document.getElementById("myform")));

function addStringToValueInJSON(json, key, string) {
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        json[i][key] = json[i][key] + string;
    }
    return json1;
}


function add() {
    addStringToValueInJSON(blah, "test", "!");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
  <input type="text" id="test" name="test" value="2">
 
</form>
```

Comment: The first problem I see is you write a `var` without value under your `console.log`

Comment: @PedroZorus THX, type mistake :D

Comment: Is your problem resolved or is the error still persists now ?

Comment: i still have the problem .. :(

Comment: You also have a problem in your "blah" `var` : an extra parenthesis at the end... Is it still blocking ?

Comment: for `{test: 2}` you want `{ http://test: 2 }` if I understand ?

Comment: this is correct, yes
And if I have {test: 2,3} => {test: http:2, http:3}

Comment: If you accepted the solution you can click on the check mark on the side of the answer to mark as resolved this thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Vanilla JS solution

```js
const JSON = {}

const formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('myform'))
for (let [key, value] of formData.entries()) {
  key += '_' // added as edit to answer at comment
  JSON[key] = `http://${value}`
}

console.log(JSON)
```

```html
<form id="myform">
  <input type="text" id="test" name="test" value="2">
</form>
```

### Multiples values version :

```js
const JSON = {}

const formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('myform'))
for (let [key, value] of formData.entries()) {
  key += '_' // added as edit to answer at comment
  const vals = value.split(',')
  
  const finalValsArray = vals.map(val => `http://${val}`)
  JSON[key] = finalValsArray.toString()
}

console.log(JSON)
```

```html
<form id="myform">
  <input type="text" id="test" name="test" value="2,3,5">
</form>
```

Comment: I was testing, I have a question, how can I define the id/key of the input field I want to do this?

Comment: You can redefinine the let `key` in my loop, Try to add `key+= "blah_"` (for example) at the first line in the loop

Comment: it is a syntax error :(

Comment: Refresh this thread, I've edited the above snippets to answer

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/h5zj9mry/30/  I have tried, is printing the key but the value is from the last input filed :(

Comment: You don't copy correctly what is in the snippets.... In your line 6, replace the `const` by `let`  then replace the whole line 7 by `key = 'blahblah'`

Comment: Sorry for bothering you :(, but is not working, no is printing all the keys + values:
https://jsfiddle.net/zo3vgxt2/14/

Comment: I got `{alex: "http://44",test: "http://11"}` in the console, isn't OK ?

Comment: I want to apply the `http://` change just to one key/value, not to every input field in the form :(

Comment: In your loop you can add a `if (key === "wantedKey") {job to create http string}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243403/discussion-between-alex-manea-and-pedrozorus).